# I am trying add text and image over video using FFmpeg lib in androoid studio

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am using FFmpeg lib for add text over video and add image over video but could not get successful. I am testing this one in a real device.

I am have already tried 2 commands for add text and add image over video but could not get proper output

```
String command[]={"ffmpeg","-i",inputpath,"-vf", "drawtext="+"\""+"fontfile=/sdcard/retro.ttf: text='Test Text'"+"\"",outputpath};


String addimg[]={"ffmpeg","-i", inputpath,"-i", imagepath ,"-filter_complex", "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,10)'" ,"-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "-c:a copy",outputpath};

public void LoadFFmpegLibrary()
{
    if(ffmpeg==null)
    {
        ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
        try {
            ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    Log.e("ffmpeg","Start to load");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure() {
                    Log.e("ffmpeg","failed to load");
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Log.e("ffmpeg","load Successfully");
                    ExcuteFfmpefLibrabry(command);
                    //    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    Log.e("ffmpeg","failed to load");
                }
            });
        } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
            // Handle if FFmpeg is not supported by device
            Log.e("ffmpeg",e.toString());
        }

    }


}

public void ExcuteFfmpefLibrabry(String command[])
{

    ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
    try {
        // to execute "ffmpeg -version" command you just need to pass "-version"
        ffmpeg.execute(command, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.e("ffmpeg","Exaction Start");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {}

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                Log.e("ffmpeg","failed to Excute Command");
                Log.e("ok",message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                Log.e("ffmpeg","Video Edited Successfully");
                Log.e("ok",message);
                // ExcuteFfmpefLibrabry(tetxcommand);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        Log.e("ffmpeg",e.toString());
    }
}
```

Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ffmpeg'
    ffmpeg: Invalid argument

I am getting an error ---> `Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ffmpeg' ffmpeg: Invalid argument`

Comment: i am getting error --->    Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ffmpeg'
    ffmpeg: Invalid argument

Comment: post whole log here to get idea about your error

Answer (score 0):

I Have seen your Code and get to know that you are using Writing minds For FFMPEG in Android Right?

and i your erro also indicate that ffmpeg is invalid  argumnet means ffmpeg is not found in FFMPEG

when you pass commands to writing mind build

for example :

you pass command like : `String command[]={"ffmpeg","-i",inputpath,outputpath};`

then ffmpeg execute below code::-- `ffmpeg ffmpeg -i inputpath outputpath`

so ffmpef cant find argument named ffmpeg in thier build

so change you command

from

```
String command[]={"ffmpeg","-i",inputpath,"-vf", "drawtext="+"\""+"fontfile=/sdcard/retro.ttf: text='Test Text'"+"\"",outputpath};


String addimg[]={"ffmpeg","-i", inputpath,"-i", imagepath ,"-filter_complex", "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,10)'" ,"-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "-c:a copy",outputpath};
```

to

```
String command[]={"-i",inputpath,"-vf", "drawtext=fontfile=/sdcard/retro.ttf: text='Test Text'",outputpath};


String addimg[]={"-i", inputpath,"-i", imagepath ,"-filter_complex", "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,10)'" ,"-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "-c:a copy",outputpath};
```